# Kafka RecordFilterStrategy does not filter records when using spring-kafka ReplyingKafkaTemplate

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

Hi I have following configuration for ReplyingKafkaTemplate and i want to filter message before consumer based on correlationID but some reason its not filter can anyone suggest what is wrong with this.

```
@Bean
public ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, FireflyResponse> replyContainer() {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, FireflyResponse> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
    RetryTemplate retryTemplate = new RetryTemplate();
    retryTemplate.setRetryPolicy(new SimpleRetryPolicy(retry));
    factory.setRetryTemplate(retryTemplate);
    factory.setConcurrency(3);
    factory.setBatchListener(true);
    factory.setAckDiscarded(true);
     factory.setRecordFilterStrategy(new RecordFilterStrategy<String, FireflyResponse>() {
        @Override
        public boolean filter(ConsumerRecord<String, FireflyResponse> consumerRecord) {
            return consumerRecord.headers().lastHeader(KafkaHeaders.CORRELATION_ID) == null;
        }
    });
    return factory.createContainer(responseTopic);
}

@Bean
public ReplyingKafkaTemplate<String, FireflyRequest, FireflyResponse> kafkaTemplate(
    ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, FireflyResponse> replyContainer) {
    ReplyingKafkaTemplate<String, FireflyRequest, FireflyResponse> template = new ReplyingKafkaTemplate<>(
        producerFactory(), replyContainer);
    template.setDefaultReplyTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(connectionTimeout));
    template.setSharedReplyTopic(true);
    return template;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The replying template ALWAYS sets the correlation id header...

```
@Override
public RequestReplyFuture<K, V, R> sendAndReceive(ProducerRecord<K, V> record, @Nullable Duration replyTimeout) {
    Assert.state(this.running, "Template has not been start()ed"); // NOSONAR (sync)
    CorrelationKey correlationId = this.correlationStrategy.apply(record);
    Assert.notNull(correlationId, "the created 'correlationId' cannot be null");
    ...
```

It needs it to correlate the reply with a request.

**EDIT**

It appears you are trying the filter the response; that is not supported; only requests are filtered.

Simply return `null` from the listener if you don't want to reply.

Comment: I tried to filter with some other attribute but still RecordFilterStrategyis not invoked

Comment: Oh; I just noticed you are trying to filter the reply; that is not supported; only requests are filtered. Just return `null` from the listener if you don't want to reply.